# Selenium: a mysterious ~60sec wait when being offline

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, offline

**Preconditions**:

- using chrome (so that I could implement offline mode based on https://medium.com/@sahajamit/selenium-chrome-dev-tools-makes-a-perfect-browser-automation-recipe-c35c7f6a2360)
- having a working online/offline switching method implemented (goOnline(), goOffline())
- making all the wait methods actually working from here: https://www.swtestacademy.com/selenium-wait-javascript-angular-ajax/ (to play safe, eliminate all the "sleep(20)" calls from it)
- choosing as simple target pages to get as possible (I used to get simple .jpg files)

**Code**:

```
...
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("page1_URL");
goOffline();
driver.get("page2_URL");
// dump here all the wait methods of medium.com
goOnline();
driver.get("page3_URL");
```

**Expected**:
Page2 (e.g. the T-Rex minigame of chrome, JS based) loads fast from cache. So all the blocking wait methods finish fast (much less than 20 seconds), we can go online again and load page3.

**Actual**:
Page2 (better phrased: the minigame) **plans sticking in the browser for 60 seconds for some reason**. Meanwhile Selenium runs through all the waits like crazy and tries getting page3 too. (Chrome logs also admit it.) At last it timeouts after 20 seconds on getting page3.

**Question**:
Why is the 60 seconds wait here?

EDIT:
I didn't manage to share the chrome logs from my workplace.
Also, running the above scenario manually, chrome remains responsive (of course) and I can traverse the 'expected' path.

Answer (score 0):

After two days of struggling (and this recent question), in the last minutes my code just started working. There are no special twists in the story however, all I did was finding out that the goOnline() method does not work, so though the JSON of the original was valid I've re-typed it anyway.

Both the goOffline()/goOnline() methods are calling the "Network.emulateNetworkConditions" method of DevTools API, with true/false value for the "offline" property. So nothing special to be done for going back online:

```
private void goOffline() {
    myWebSocket.send("{\"id\":" + counter++
            + ",\"method\":\"Network.emulateNetworkConditions\",\"params\":{\"offline\":true,\"latency\":0,\"downloadThroughput\":-1,\"uploadThroughput\":-1}}");
}

private void goOnline() {
    myWebSocket.send("{\"id\":" + counter++
            + ",\"method\":\"Network.emulateNetworkConditions\",\"params\":{\"offline\":false,\"latency\":0,\"downloadThroughput\":-1,\"uploadThroughput\":-1}}");
}
```